# Display Javascript "return" value in a div

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following script from the [e164.js](https://github.com/pdeschen/e164.js) library.
Normally from chrome debugger, I'll use `e164.lookup('44123486789`); and I'll get the value: `Object {Country: "United Kingdom", Code: "UK"}`

How can I read a phone number from a html div and display the returned result in another html div?
for example say

```
<div id="phone">44123486789</div>
```

and write the result to:

`<div id="country"></div>`

Thanks guys.

Here is the script:

```
    (function() {
var lookup, prefixes = {
  "1201": [ "US", "United States" ],
  "1202": [ "US", "United States" ],
  "1203": [ "US", "United States" ],
  "1204": [ "CA", "Canada" ],
   "44": [ "GB", "United Kingdom" ],
};
lookup = function(phone) {
  if (phone.length) {
    var prefix, c = phone.length;
    for (c; c >= 0; c=c-1) {
      prefix = phone.substring(0, c);
      if (prefixes[prefix]) {
        return { country: prefixes[prefix][1], code: prefixes[prefix][0] };
      }
    }
  }
};
if (typeof exports !== "undefined"){
  exports.lookup = lookup;
}
if (typeof window !== "undefined"){
  window.e164 = { lookup : lookup};
}
})();
```

Comment: ?? What result? What div??

Comment: Does `div` has `id` attribute?

Comment: You can assign any div id to it; I forgot to include the html part.

Comment: `document.getElementById('yourDivId').innerHTML = 'your result here in HTML format'`

Answer (score 0):

```
var phone = document.getElementById('phone').innerHTML;
var country = lookup(phone).country;
document.getElementById('country').innerHTML = country;
```

It'll need to go inside that anonymous function you have there (since the function lookup is defined inside the scope of that outer function). And that outer anonymous function will need to run after those two divs (and the phone number) are present -- you should probably wait for the load event on window.

Comment: Using this snippet, I just get the error message when the page is loaded.`Uncaught ReferenceError: e164 is not defined`

Comment: Can you show us the whole page? You're probably referencing e164before e164 is loaded.

Comment: This is how I tried to define the div containers for both phone and country; then engage the `e164.lookup` function. But it's not working.

Comment: `<body>
<div id="phone">9956335486352</div>
<div id="country"></div>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('phone').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('country').innerHTML;
var country = e164.lookup('phone');
</script>
</body>`

Comment: Did you not include that whole function you included in your question? You need that (it's what defines e164). And you need that code to run before your e164.lookup call.